# How to transfer data from all table in database to azure data lake destination?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

I have two tables tbl1 and tbl2. I want to create a package which will read the data from tbl1 and tbl2 and transfer the data to Azure data lake as two files `tbl1.txt and tbl2.txt`.

What I have done is `created Execute SQL task` with query 
`select name from sys.tables` ,which will return table names and loop through that result and store into store variable. But Oledb Source doesn't accept query like

```
select * from @[user::tablName] (a variable which has a table name)
```

Comment: Are you using SSIS, your source is Azure db or non Azure db ?

Comment: @Ven Using SSIS and Source will Azure Db or Normal SQL Server

Comment: Use data flow task, create a variable on designer. data mode, select query from variable

Comment: Based on all your other questions you need to understand something: SSIS does not deal with dynamic metadata. It just doesn't work. You need to explicitly deinfe source and target columns and their mappings. Don't try and do this dynamically. Maybe you need to look into BISM

Answer (score 0):

Frame the entire query in the variable

```
select * from <variablename>
```

And then use `select query from variable`  option to fetch the data.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)